# Join two tables in SQLite and Count

Tags: sqlite, join, count

I have two tables named "likes" and "comments" and I want to have a table which has counts of likes and comments for each specific user, I wrote following query in SQLite but result is not true for all users, count values for users in both tables are multiple of number of likes and number of comments.

```
SELECT 
  likes.liker_name, likes.liker_id, likes.profile_picture , 
  COUNT(comments.commenter_name) AS comment_count, COUNT( likes.liker_id) AS like_count
FROM likes  
LEFT JOIN comments 
  ON likes.liker_name = comments.commenter_name 
GROUP BY 
  likes.liker_name 
ORDER BY 
  COUNT( likes.liker_id) DESC
```

How can I get correct value of count for users that exist in both tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is: Some users have comments but no likes, others have likes but no comments, some have both and some have none. Therefore I suggest using a union query and summing that one again

```
SELECT
    u.name, u.id, u.profile_picture,
    SUM(u.like_count) AS like_count, SUM(u.comment_count) AS comment_count
FROM (
    SELECT
        liker_name AS name, liker_id AS id, profile_picture,
        COUNT(*) AS like_count, 0 AS comment_count
    FROM
        likes
    GROUP BY
        liker_name, liker_id, profile_picture
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        commenter_name AS name, commenter_id AS id, profile_picture,
        0 AS like_count, COUNT(*) AS comment_count
    FROM
        comments
    GROUP BY
        commenter_name, commenter_id, profile_picture
) AS u
GROUP BY
    u.name, u.id, u.profile_picture
```

If you have a separate user table you could also left join the likes count and the comments count subqueries to the user table

```
SELECT
    u.name, u.id, u.profile_picture, l.cnt AS like_count, c.cnt AS comment_count
FROM
    users u
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT liker_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM likes
        GROUP BY liker_id
        ) AS l
        ON u.user_id = l.liker_id
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT commenter_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM comments
        GROUP BY commenter_id
        ) AS c
        ON u.user_id = c.commenter_id
WHERE l.cnt > 0 OR c.cnt > 0
```

No matter how you make it, you must count the comments and the likes in separate subqueries. If you count after joining you are summing on a result where records might be duplicated (the ones on the left side) and you are getting the wrong count.